# Moving data back and forth between p and textarea, but preserving linebreaks

Tags: javascript, html, regex, textarea

This should be a simple one for someone who gets regex.

I have a field on a page that is pre-populated by php, but is editable using javascript. I need to be able to preserve linebreaks when swapping between 'edit mode' and 'fixed mode'.

I understand that textareas like their linebreaks to be `\n`, and normal html likes to see `<br />` tags. I'm using the function `.replace(/\n/g, '<br />')` to get from textarea to div, but I'm not sure what to use to get the field back into the textarea and keep the linebreaks.

Also I'm not sure whether just replacing `<br />` with `\n` is safe, in case the browser decides it likes `<br>` better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set `white-space: pre-wrap` in CSS then the line breaks are preserved with no need to replace them with `br` tags.

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/jVBdm/

**Update:** `white-space: pre-wrap` will not work in IE6 and IE7 (thanks Kenneth J for pointing this out) but `white-space: pre` will work — which may or may not be enough for you. You can use a conditional style for IE6 and IE7 to use `pre` and use use `pre-wrap` on modern browsers.

Comment: Simple, elegant and clean. Thanks

Comment: If you are concerned with browser compatibility I'm not sure this is the best choice. This does not work in IE6 or IE7. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html

Comment: `white-space: pre` should work in IE6+ - maybe that's enough.

Answer (score 1):

It does not really matter whether you use `<br />` (xhtml) or `<br>` browsers should parse them exactly the same.

I think you would use the same break tag you inserted.

To be safe, I suppose you could just do both.

```
txt =  txt.replace(/<br \/>|<br>/gi, '\n')
```

Comment: I was able to handle it with CSS, which is cleaner. Thanks anyway